Has the average number of co-authors on papers published at the top CS conferences increased in last several years and if yes why?
It seems to me that over time the average number of co-authors on papers published at the top Computer Science conferences (and perhaps journals as well) has increased.
I suppose this may has something to do with the increasing number of active researchers in these fields and the increasing difficulty in contributing to problems that are or may be considered important.
Question: Has the average number of authors on each paper published at the top conferences (and possibly also top journals) actually increased? If yes, what are the likely  reasons for this?

I'm also unsure if such specific questions are as useful as more general ones such as Is there an inflation in the number of authors per paper?, What is the average number of articles written per author in a year and has it increased recently?

@Anyon It might  be useful since the dynamics which may cause multiple authorship in papers at top conferences may differ from the rest.

@Anyon I agree about the first post that you suggest, but not about the second: authors-per-paper and papers-per-author are two very different metrics that are not necessarily related to each other.

I don't have data, but I suspect you are correct. The competition is fierce, so one has to join forces, the number of researchers and resources increased and people are working in large labs or groups now.

@FedericoPoloni Yeah, that's fair.

Here's a relevant paper from 2017. Unfortunately, it only covers publications up to 2014 and doesn't distinguish between conferences and journals: https://doi.org/10.1007/s11192-016-2214-9

@Anyon Thank you.
